# [UIThreadSafeNode createPeripheral]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash

I tried to search about createPeripheral and i had no luck finding any information about it. Is there anyone here who had the same crash as this?

[UIThreadSafeNode createPeripheral]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Which class does createPeripheral belong to?
How do you handle this crash?

note: there's not much information in the crash log

```
stackTrace =
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x31dcd2bb <redacted> + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39a7297f objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreFoundation                      0x31dd0e07 <redacted> + 170
3   CoreFoundation                      0x31dcf531 <redacted> + 392
4   CoreFoundation                      0x31d26f68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   UIKit                               0x33d4bf99 <redacted> + 52
6   UIKit                               0x33bda80f <redacted> + 38
7   UIKit                               0x33bda431 <redacted> + 404
8   UIKit                               0x33f1ad19 <redacted> + 236
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39e98621 <redacted> + 80
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39e98621 <redacted> + 80
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39e894b7 <redacted> + 22
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39e8adcb <redacted> + 226
12  CoreFoundation                      0x31da0f3b <redacted> + 1290
13  CoreFoundation                      0x31d13ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
14  CoreFoundation                      0x31d13d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
15  GraphicsServices                    0x358d72eb GSEventRunModal + 74
16  UIKit                               0x33c29301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
...
);
```

Comment: Can you post the code which is causing this crash?

Comment: Also you can add breakpoint for `objc_exception_throw` and check the stack trace leading to this crash.

Comment: Actually, i don't exactly know which code is causing the crash. that's what i want to know as well. i only have the crash log which doesn't do any help.

Comment: I have exactly the same crash report. Did you figure out what was causing the crash?

Comment: No. i ended up ignoring the crash because I couldn't really find a way to repro/fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for adding to an old post, but I do have a strong reproduction case for this bug. Open any software keyboard on the iPhone6+ (or iPhone6+ simulator) in a WebView. Put something in the paste-buffer, then click the paste button.

I haven't solved it yet, but I thought this might help if anyone is lost in google for this bug.

Comment: Kudos for thinking about fellow Googlers! However, this would probably fit a comment to the original question/answer better than a seperate answer, since this technically is *not* an answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Unfortunately, new user here. Can't comment unless it's on my own stuff.

Comment: Did you find a way how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've just got a similar crash report.
There is UIWebBrowserView in the call stack. Maybe it is a bug in it.

Our application uses UIWebView to show a simple html page, and I receive random crashes in WebView regulary. I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error occured when I tried to customize -inputaccessoryview on contenteditable div.

I believe createPeripheral has something to deal with Keyboard display as

```
webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

solved this crash for me.